# Правильно ли будет добавить div или другой тег в textarea html?

Tags: html, html5, textarea

Я не могу сделать так:

```
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Могу ли я сделать так?

```
<textarea>
    <div></div>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textarea - это текстовая область (область куда вы можете писать символы), а div используются для определения частей документа, чтобы их можно было идентифицировать, когда необходима уникальная классификация. Как раз таки первый код вы можете выполнить, а вот второй - нет.